# problem when picture next to the text design css : the picture does not next to the text as design

Tags: html, css

I am newbie with html css and trying to code a very simple page follow an online tutorial. And here is my problem.

Here is my code

```
   https:// codepen.io/anhbui2904/pen/jOxeQgw
```

As you can see, here is my result (my page), my icon's picture is lying above the texts.

[image: Problem 1]

Here is the design

[image: Design]

In the design, the icon's picture is lying next to the texts.

You can see in my code, I thought that may be my problem is because of the css file.

Could you please give me some advice for this problem ? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: The code should be in the question itself

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove `flex-wrap: wrap;` from the `.row` class and have to add `align-items: center;` to the `.row` class. Hope your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `flex-wrap: wrap;` from the `.row`, and it will work.